# openssl s_client allows connection while curl does not

Tags: openssl, curl

```
grief@rocket:/$ curl https://wrong.host.badssl.com
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'wrong.host.badssl.com'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.


grief@rocket:/$ echo "Q" | openssl s_client wrong.host.badssl.com:443 2>&1|grep Verification
Verification: OK
```

How can I test if the certificate matches the hostname using `openssl (1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable hostname verification using the `-verify_hostname <host>` option.